# Get the JSon data from URL

Tags: jquery, json

I  want to display data currency value(3.8945) only  from the https://openexchangerates.orgapilatest.json?app_id=0277d31956db4d57af7207ca1ab782a5&symbols=MYR to my web page TextBox using jQuery.suggest me a way to do.Json result as:

```
{
  "disclaimer": "Usage subject to terms: https://openexchangerates.org/terms",
  "license": "https://openexchangerates.org/license",
  "timestamp": 1517839199,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "MYR": 3.8945
  }
}
```

I tried this way but nothing to display my text box.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form runat="server"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <script>
    $.getJSON('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=0277d31956db4d57af7207ca1ab782a5&symbols=MYR
', function(data) {
      var Rate = 'rates: ${data.rates}'
       $("#txtRate").val(Rate);
    });
    </script>    
</body>
</form> 
</html>
```

Comment: your link is broken. 
Use jquery.Ajax
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Your question is basically, 'How do I retrieve JSON using jQuery'. In which case, read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: I tried but nothing to display my text box, how to get the currency value and display to my textbox.

Comment: `data.rates["MYR"]` <-- Please try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

You have to access the value as `data.rates["MYR"]`.

You can use `toFixed(3)` to round to 3 decimal points in javascript/jquery.

```
$.getJSON('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=0277d31956db4d57af7207ca1ab782a5&symbols=MYR', 
function(data) {
   var Rate = 'rates: ' + parseFloat( data.rates["MYR"] ).toFixed(3);
   $("#txtRate").val(Rate);
});
```

Comment: Thanks eddie i got it but it is displayed in text box rates: 3.894007, I want to display the numbers only how to cut the rates plz suggest to me

Comment: @brite Please check my updated answer. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: var Rate =  data.rates["MYR"];
   $("#txtRate").val(Rate);

Comment: You can use `toFixed(3)` to round off the value to 3 decimal places.